# Html.CheckBox renders two checkboxes

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I try to serialize `<%: Html.CheckBox("Something", true) %>` in jquery (using form.serialize()) I get two checkboxes, one says true, and the other false.  I am aware that MVC renders true, false for checkboxes that are true, so if I wasn't coming through javascript, I'd just check for the presence of true, but how do I know if my checkbox is checked after doing form.serialize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the output HTML - you'll see that the Html.Checkbox() actually renders an additional hidden input in there with the same name. That's why you're seeing two values. I believe MS decided to do this so that a proper bool gets POSTed (rather than a string value of 'on' for checkboxes).

To get around this, I never use Html.Checkbox() helper anymore, I always just write the full HTML myself.

Comment: Seems like the standard html checkbox sets it to "on" if it is checked rather than a boolean.  How can I convert the value "on" to true before sending it to my server?

Comment: You can override the value of checkboxes so that when they're POSTed, a specific value of your choice is sent. So, what you could do is have: <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" value="true" />. When that checkbox is checked, the jQuery form serialization will have mycheckbox=true. When it's not checked, no values will be serialized.

Comment: It's interesting, I had added a property in my model that matches the names of the checkbox control, but the model property was always false even though the serialized string had the value true for the checkbox.  I had to add an extra parameter in my action method to collect the checkbox value.

Comment: +1 for the great explanation of both how MS did things and how to override the value that works for jquery serialize. It all makes so much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
var isChecked = $('#idofyourcheckbox').is(':checked');
```

As far as the values stored in the `form.serialize()` string are concerned they are destined to go to the server where you can simply work with boolean properties.